# Custom JSON response with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I just implemented [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) in my app and now I'm trying to *trim* my JSON response so it doesn't return everything for the Model in question.  Here's what my `as_json` method looks like:

```html
def as_json(options={})
  super(:only => [:serial_number],
    :include => {
      :device_functions => { :only => [:can_scan, :can_brute] },
   :scan_options => { :methods => :scan_ip_list}
 }
  )
end
```

Which currently returns:

```html
{
  "serial_number": "abcdefg12345",
  "device_functions": [
    {
      "can_scan": true
    }
  ],
  "scan_options": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "device_id": 11,
      "created_at": "2016-02-05T02:26:26.090Z",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-05T02:26:26.090Z",
      "scan_ip_list": [
        "10.10.10.100-110",
        "10.10.10.1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get rid of extra data that I don't need, such as `id`, `device_id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` now.

Also, using `:only =>` worked find for the `:device_functions` response, but I had to use `:methods =>` for `:scan_options` since I'm using `acts_as_taggable_on`... at least that's what I read and was the only option that returned something (I tried `:only =>` and `:include =>` as well but they returned an empty hash:

```html
{
  "serial_number": "abcdefg12345",
  "device_functions": [
    {
      "can_scan": true
    }
  ],
  "scan_options": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `:only` option to your `:scan_options` hash too:

```
# ...
      :scan_options => { :methods => :scan_ip_list, :only => :scan_ip_list }
```

Also, FWIW, you should probably merge into `option` in case you ever want to supply some of your own options, so:

```
# ...
  super options.merge( :only => ...etc.
```

Comment: Wow, I tried all sorts of combinations.  That works though!